Token refresh causes end-to-end test failure
i need to implement a end to end test for a web application, Calling the API and using data from the database, but this process requires authorization, which is where the problem lies
 private readonly HttpClient _client;

 public AlertControllerIntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
 {
     _client = new HttpClient();
     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "exampletoken");
     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Apikey", "exampleapikey");
 }

in the testing class, i create a _client to call the api and carry out HTTP communication.
however, once the token refreshes, the result is Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
Is there any way for me to find out when the current token has expired and automatically obtain the latest token?
